# How can init command be useful for me?

Tags: init

I was reading about the `init` command.

I found that `init 0` is the same like `poweroff` and `init 6` is the same like `reboot`.

Why are there more than one command to do the exactly same thing in the same way (as I understood)?

Second, `init 1` puts the system in single user mode. Does that mean it has no effect on my machine while I'm the only user? Or that mode has constraints?

Comment: Why do you think only 1 way to shutdown is better in an Operating System ?

Comment: I don't think I'm just asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always good to have more than only one option to do things.

`init 1` means

```
Single-user mode, all files-systems unmounted but not root, all processes
except console processes killed
```

This is mostly used for administrative tasks, I guess it is not what you want, no GUI, only console.

Comment: [Actually, it means _rescue mode_ on Ubuntu 15 and later](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132), which [is not a shut down mode](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/emergency-and-rescue-mode-bootstrap.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `init` command allows you to set what is called the current system runlevel.

All Linux machines have seven runlevels, which are responsible for managing certain system actions and behaviors. On a classical SystemV installation, each runlevel would be part of the boot procedure:

- Runlevel 0 (Machine off)
- Runlevel 1 (Singleuser / Diagnostics Mode)
- Runlevels 2-4 (Bootup and service start)
- Runlevel 5 (Fully booted system, all services online)
- Runlevel 6 (Going down for restart)

The `init` (and `telinit`) commands allow you to specify what runlevel to move init and the system to.

Note, however, that the entire runlevel concept is now a bit antiquated due to the creation of the service model (through Upstart and systemd (`service apache2 start`)), and should be considered deprecated in favor of using proper systemd commands.

Using runlevels now runs the risk of terminating essential services, so it is often advised to *not* use the `init` or `telinit` commands.

Comment: Nice answer! A small quibble: didn't recent versions of Ubuntu move away from upstart, to systemd? I thought upstart wasn't used anymore.

Comment: @NickWeinberg Ah, yeah, that's right. I'll edit the post. It's late here and I'm not thinking properly lol

Comment: Many Linux machines in fact _do not have run levels at all_, nowadays, [systemd having declared them "obsolete"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132).